# Convert day numbers to string in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I have the date like this in wordpress, I get it from a custom metabox where is stored like this, `23/02/2012`, now how can I set `wp_locale` in WP or something like that, and I need to convert the date to: `Monday 23 February 2012`, but I need also to set the language, thats why I need that `wp_locale` because that output will be in Dutch.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format can be converted with the code below as a guide.

```
date('l j F Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '23/02/2012')))
```

The `str_replace` is necessary because with `/` PHP assumes `m/d/y` American date format, not the European `d/m/y`.

As for doing this in Wordpress with i18n support, you might consider http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n

```
date_i18n('l j F Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '23/02/2012')))
```

Comment: You are the man it works, do you know if it's possible to display the day and month in Dutch, or I need to do an array and compare the results?

Comment: That's the purpose of `date_i18n`, to reformat the date *and* translate it's components to the target language. [The source for date_i18n](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/functions.php#L70) uses the global `$wp_locale` variable to translate the date components. If their not being translated your problem is likely with your Wordpress' i18n configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there are other ways to do this, but I'd do it as follows:

Upon 'save_post':

```
$date = explode ('/',$_POST["date_field"]);
$date = $date[1].'/'.$date[0].'/'.$date[2]; // dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy
$s = strtotime($date); /* UNIX TIMESTAMP */
```

and then store the Unix timestamp in the database.

Upon 'amdin_init' you'll need to do the exact opposite to load the date in the right format in the metabox:

```
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
if ($custom["date_field"][0]) {
    $d = date("d/m/Y",$custom["date_field"][0]); // convert unix timestamp
} else {
    $d = "";
}
```

And in your template file, use php functions `setlocale` and `strftime` to display the date:

```
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$d = $custom["date_field"][0];
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl_NL');
$s = strftime('%#d %B %Y',$s);
```

This should output something like **13 January 2012**.